# Expand glob with flag inserted before each filename

Tags: bash, wildcards

I have a program that expects arguments in the following syntax:

```
prog [-f filename | -g filename1 filename2] ...
```

Each filename must be prefixed with the `-f` flag. For example, the following are valid invocations of `prog`:

```
prog -f a.txt -g b.txt c.txt -f d.txt
prog -g a.txt b.txt -g c.txt d.txt
prog -f a.txt -f b.txt -f c.txt
```

…but the following are not:

```
prog -f a.txt b.txt
prog -f a.txt -g b.txt
prog a.txt
```

In my case, I only care about the `-f` option.

I have a lot of files in a directory, all of which end in `.txt`. They look like this:

```
important-files/
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── c.txt
├── d.txt
└── filename with spaces.txt
```

I would like to avoid needing to list out every file one by one. Normally, I would use a straightforward glob for this:

```
$ prog important-files/*.txt
```

But this doesn’t work, since it produces the following invalid invocation:

```
$ prog important-files/a.txt important-files/b.txt important-files/c.txt important-files/d.txt 'important-files/filename with spaces.txt'
```

…when I really want this invocation:

```
$ prog -f important-files/a.txt -f important-files/b.txt -f important-files/c.txt -f important-files/d.txt -f 'important-files/filename with spaces.txt'
```

…since each filename must be prefixed with `-f` in order for `prog` to understand they shouldn’t be interpreted like `-g`.

What is the shortest way to use a glob and prefix each of the files it expands to with a flag?

Comment: meanwhile in ZSH this is `*.txt(P:\\-f:)`

Comment: @thrig It's just `*.txt(P:-f:)` in fact (Why would you put a backslash there?).

Comment: Out of interest, is this program `pip`, and the flag `-r`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `printf` and an `xargs` supporting nul-delimited input:

```
printf -- '-f\0%s\0' important-files/*.txt | xargs -0 prog
```

`printf` loops the format string over the arguments, so for each filename in the expansion of the glob, it will print `-f` and the filename separated by the null character. `xargs` then reads this and converts it into arguments for `prog`. The `--` needed since some implementations of `printf` have trouble with a leading `-` in the format string. Alternately, the `-` can be replaced with `\055`, which is standard.

Same principle as [Rakesh's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445442/70524), but using the wildcard expansion directly.

Comment: Why null characters usage needed, why not just double quotes, like: `printf ' -f "%s"' important-files/*.txt | xargs prog`?

Comment: If the filenames contain quotes or backslashes, it's going to be difficult to appropriately escape them. The null character is not allowed in filenames, so it's generally the safest character for separating arbitrary (but valid) filenames.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In my case is needed to add `--`, because `printf '-f\0%s\0' important-files/*.txt` gives the error: `bash: printf: -f: invalid option`. The `printf -- '-f\0%s\0' important-files/*.txt` works.

Comment: Sigh. Neither zsh nor GNU nor busybox `printf` had problems with it. Thanks, I'll add the `--`.

Comment: My understanding is that `xargs` will use its input to pass args to `prog`.  But if there are too many args, it will split them up and invoke `prog` multiple times.  Do we have the possibility here of splitting the args in the wrong place, e.g. calling `prog -f a.txt -f b.txt ... -f m.txt -f` and then calling `prog n.txt -f o.txt ...` ?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma yes, the possibility exists. But if that were to happen, every answer here would fail too, either because of splitting, or because of argument length limit being exceeded. I'm counting on the program doing argument parsing early on and failing hard, of course.

Answer (score 11):

[`zsh` now has a `P` glob qualifier for that](/a/445515).

For older versions, you can always use:

```
f=(*.txt)
prog -f$^f
```

[`$^f`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-rc_002c-array-expansion-style) enables the [`rcexpandparam` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-RCEXPANDPARAM) for the expansion of `$f`, where arrays are expanded in a style similar to that of the `rc` shell.

In `rc` (or `zsh -o rcexpandparam`):

```
f=(*.txt)
prog -f$f
```

Is expanded to `prog -fa.txt -fb.txt`, a bit as if you had written in csh (or other shells supporting brace expansion): `prog -f{a.txt,b.txt}`.

(note that it's different from `*.txt(P:-f:)` in that the file name is glued to the option `-ffile.txt` as opposed to passing two arguments `-f` `file.txt`. Many commands including all those that use the standard `getopt()` API to parse options support both  ways passing arguments to options).

`fish` also expands arrays like that:

```
set f *.txt
prog -f$f
```

In `bash`, you can emulate it with:

```
f=(*.txt)
prog "${f[@]/#/-f}"
```

With `ksh93`:

```
f=(*.txt)
prog "${f[@]/*/-f\0}"
```

For `-f` and the corresponding `file.txt`s to be  passed as separate arguments, another option with `zsh` using its array zipping operator:

```
o=-f f=(*.txt); prog ${o:^^f}
```

You could extend that for your `-g` option. Assuming there's an even number of `txt` files:

```
o=(-g '') f=(*.txt); prog ${o:^^f}
```

Would pass `-g` options with two files at a time. Similar to what you'd get with:

```
printf -- '-g\0%s\0%s\0' *.txt | xargs -r0 prog
```

Comment: Would the bash example work?  You end up with elements like `-f a.txt` instead of `-f` `a.txt`.

Comment: @m0dular, no, you end up with `-fa.txt` like for the zsh/rc/fish approaches above. Applications using `getopt()` treat  it the same as `-f` `a.txt`, I can't tell about the OP's application (though it's unlikely to be using `getopt()` if there are options that take more than one argument). That's mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 9):

With bash, try:

```
args=()
for f in important-files/*.txt
do
    args+=(-f "$f")
done
prog "${args[@]}"
```

Note that this will work not merely with filenames that contain blanks but also with filenames that contain single or double quotes or even newlines.

#### Easy interactive use

For easy interactive use, define a function:

```
progf() { args=(); for f in  "$@"; do args+=(-f "$f"); done; prog "${args[@]}"; }
```

This function can be used as follows:

```
progf important-files/*.txt
```

To make the function definition permanent, place it in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: This admittedly works, and it’s *somewhat* palatable in a script, but it’s not terribly pleasant when I really just want to run a one-off command interactively.

Comment: @AlexisKing OK, but for palatable interactive use, I would define a function (see update).

Answer (score 8):

As thrig already mentioned in a comment:

```
zsh -c 'prog *.txt(P:-f:)'
```

This uses the [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `P` which prepends a separate word to each glob match. Like almost all of zsh's glob qualifiers, bash has nothing similar.

If you want to have completion for `prog`, run `zsh` interactively then type `prog *.txt(P:-f:)`. The very first time you run zsh interactively, it'll prompt you to set a configuration. If you don't care about zsh, either pick the option to make a blank `.zshrc` (but then you'll miss on some zsh features that need to be activated explicitly) or pick `1` and go through the menus to activate the recommended defaults.

Answer (score 5):

One. method to do this is with the GNU find/xargs duo:

```
cd important-files && \
find . -name '*.txt'  -printf '-f\0%p\0' | xargs -0 -r  prog
```

Comment: Note that this will change the working directory for `prog`, which may affect things like relative paths used by the program.

Comment: Why are you changing the directory? Just do `find important-files …` instead. This’ll also avoid the problem mentioned by @Kusalananda.

Comment: To avoid hitting the arguments limit since the "important-files" token will be tacked to all filenames without yielding any info.

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly, you can always define a function like:

```
prog_f() (
  for i do
    set -- "$@" -f "$i"
    shift
  done
  exec prog "$@"
)
```

Comment: Why are the subshell and `exec` needed here?